# How to enable sound on Base Game Activity in Andengine?

Tags: andengine

I am developing a game using **Andengine** , I am using a **Base Game Activity** with multiple scenes. I want to load a **background music** in it.But I dont know **how to enable sound in engine** while using Base Game Activity.I found this code in net to enable sound .

```
return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, 
   new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera).setNeedsMusic(true));
```

But this one is written in onLoadScene() and I dont know how to impliment onLoadScene() in basegame actvity.Do I can override onLoadScene() in base game activity or is there any other ways to achive this please help me...

Any Suggestions are Valid to me and Advanced thanks to alll....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with the Help of [Jmr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499485/jmr499485) Here is the code

```
final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,
            new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
    engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(true);
    engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true);
```